# Why did the pronunciation of Orleans change in New Orleans, while those of French borrowed words were retained?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, french

Words like *rendezvous, faux pas, a la carte* are still pronounced the same way as they are pronounced in the French language. Why was New Orleans an exception to this?

Comment: I don't know, but when you find out, maybe you can tell me why Versailles, Illinois is pronounced "Ver.Sales'"

Comment: @TariqIbrahim Mr deadrat was my father.  No need for the honorific for me. The comment was intended to convey the notion that non-French speakers in Anglophone areas often Anglicize foreign names.  If your feelings were really bruised by what you took to be a snide comment, then I will be happy to delete the comment.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @deadrat Sir, It is fine. I just seek an answer to my question, that is all. I find it rather weird when people get sneered at for pronouncing faux as fox, while its perfectly okay to pronounce new Orleans as new orlenz.

Comment: Mr. Tariq - I wouldn't label that comment by @deadrat as "snide," and I doubt it was intended that way. It's simply a thought-provoking acknowledgement that New Orleans is not a lone "exception". Come to think of it, we don't pronounce "Paris" the same way they do over in France, either. And [here are some more to ponder](http://mentalfloss.com/article/50967/20-towns-named-other-towns-pronounced-differently).

Comment: It is a fallacy to think that all, or even most, French words borrowed into English are spoken with authentic French pronunciation. Counterexamples abound, which is what deadrat was hinting at. Consider _chaise longue_ (noun+adj) meaning in French "long chair". Because Americans could neither pronounce nor understand it, it is now spelled _chaise lounge_ (meaningless "adjective"+mangled-spelling/wrong "noun") and pronounced "chayce lownj"

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: also French /ɛ/ is pronounced as English /eɪ/ in a multitude of words (even in words where English /ɛ/ would be possible like *crêpe*, *fête* and *chaise*)

Answer (score 3):

The following interesting [extract](http://www.nytimes.com/fodors/top/features/travel/destinations/unitedstates/louisiana/neworleans/fdrs_feat_110_10.html?n=Top%2FFeatures%2FTravel%2FDestinations%2FUnited%20States%2FLouisiana%2FNew%20Orleans) from the *New York Times* suggests that the local accent at times prevails on the original pronunciations:

> - ***New Orleans, like many other cities, has its own peculiarities in terms of speech*** . Because it was founded by the French, the city has many street names that a visitor might be inclined to pronounce true to the French. In fact, local pronunciation is quite different. There are also some local terms that can be confusing if you're not aware of them.
> - Various theories claim that the similar accents found in such places as Boston, New York, and New Orleans evolved because people from countries like Ireland, Germany, and Italy settled early on in these port towns. In New Orleans, you will not hear locals with thick, Georgia-peach drawls. But you might hear some "dese, dem, dat," and "dose," as in "Who dat say dey gonna beat dem Saints?!"
> - One thing that always sets visitors apart is their reference to the trolley. It's a streetcar in New Orleans, not a trolley. And many locals say New-ahl-e-yuns, not New Or-lenz, N'aw-lins, or New Or-leenz. Still, you'll probably fit in fine with the easier-to-pronounce New Or-lenz; the key things to avoid are placing the emphasis on "new" rather than "Or" and using a long "e" sound in "leans." But -- here's a curveball -- it is Or-leenz Street.
> - ***You need to forget any French you've studied when pronouncing street names. This is where the Texan in the back of class whom everybody snickered at gets his revenge***. If you ask what direction Freret (Frer-ay, in French) Street is, you will be met by a blank stare. (The correct pronunciation is Fer-et.) Burgundy Street is Bur-gun-dee; Carondelet is Cahr-ahn-duh-let; Chartres is Chart-ers; Conti is Con-tie; Iberville is Eye-berville; and Tchoupitoulas is Chop-a-tool-us. And if someone asks you, "Where y'at?," he or she is saying howdy, not asking where you are.